# Code that changes chart position requires my target sheet to be Activated?

Tags: vba, excel

I use this code to dynamically change the size of a chart and its position on the sheet. As I add a new line of data daily, I shift a bunch of charts down on the page to line up with the new last row. What I DON'T understand is why I need the sheet with the charts on it to be activated in order for this to work properly.

Before anyone asks, my `lastrow` value is being retrieved explictly, so none of my values are being interpreted from an `ActiveSheet`. However, I still have this issue... Here is my subroutine that takes some arguments to adjust a specific chart:

```
Private Sub FitChart(mainsheet As Worksheet, mainchart As String, firstcol As String, secondcol As String, topoffset As Integer, bottomoffset As Integer, lastrow As Long)
'This sub is used to line up the charts with the lastrow of data on each sheet

mainsheet.ChartObjects(mainchart).Chart.Parent.Height = mainsheet.Range(firstcol & lastrow + topoffset & ":" & secondcol & lastrow + bottomoffset).Height
mainsheet.ChartObjects(mainchart).Chart.Parent.Width = mainsheet.Range(firstcol & lastrow + topoffset & ":" & secondcol & lastrow + bottomoffset).Width
mainsheet.ChartObjects(mainchart).Chart.Parent.Top = mainsheet.Range(firstcol & lastrow + topoffset & ":" & secondcol & lastrow + bottomoffset).Top
mainsheet.ChartObjects(mainchart).Chart.Parent.Left = mainsheet.Range(firstcol & lastrow + topoffset & ":" & secondcol & lastrow + bottomoffset).Left

End Sub
```

Here's an example of how I call it:

```
'Worksheets("main chart").Activate

'Change chart position
Call FitChart(Worksheets("main chart"), "Chart 92", "W", "AH", -30, -1, lastrow)
```

With the `Activate` line commented out, the charts line up unevenly - note the red line is what I want lining up with my `lastrow` of data:

[image: Image1]

But when I un-comment out the `Activate` line:

[image: Image2]

It lines up perfectly - What gives??? This is very minor but the functionality of it is driving me nuts. I also have 50 + sheets that are using this code, if I'm running in sequence that's a lot of unnecessary activating...

Comment: I've tested this with some data, but can't recreate the issue:  Do you have any code to auto-fit the rows/columns when you activate the sheet?  Is your Chart set to "Move and size with cells"?  Also, you can reduce `mainsheet.ChartObjects(mainchart).Chart.Parent.Height` to `mainsheet.ChartObjects(mainchart).Height`, etc. **{EDIT}** *Following comment by @Rory, I was able to recreate this by changing the graph-sheet to a non-100% zoom.  ActiveSheet zoom is irrelevant*

Comment: Are the zoom settings the same for every sheet?

Comment: @Chronocidal I was able to get rid of `.Chart.Parent` and it still works the same but I have the same issue. I don't have any code to auto-fit rows or columns.

Comment: @Rory The zoom settings are NOT the same - what part of my code is contingent on that??

Comment: The positioning part. ;) (it's a bug, IMO)

Comment: @Rory Realllllly now... Here I was losing my mind over some value assignments or something. I guess it's good to know that it's out of my control... I need the zoom settings the way they are due to the amount of data/charts I'm trying to view in one screen.

Comment: There's a similar bug with ActiveX Object sizes caused by changing Screen resolution/aspect ratio (e.g. docking/undocking a Laptop at a docking station with a bigger screen) which causes them to grow/shrink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to mark this question as "solved", this has been confirmed to be a bug - There is no way to have this work without activating or selecting the worksheets. I'm sticking to the solution of using `Worksheet().Activate` to get my intended result.

Answer (score 2):

As identified in the question Comments, this is a bug when the sheet is both **A)** Not Active and **B)** Not set to 100% Zoom.

The zoom of the sheet that *is* Active is irrelevant - 100%, 200%, 50%, the same as the sheet with the Chart on: none of that matters.

This following code will take a SheetName as string, and let you change the Zoom without changing ActiveSheet.  It *will*, however, select and unselect sheets.

```vb
Sub ChangeZoom(ResetSheet As String, Optional NewZoom As Double = 100)
    Dim CurrentZoom As Variant, CurrentSheet As String
    CurrentZoom = ActiveWindow.Zoom 'Store current Zoom
    CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet.Name 'Store current Sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(CurrentSheet, ResetSheet)).Select 'Select current sheet and Sheet to Zoom
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = NewZoom 'Change Zoom
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CurrentSheet).Select 'Select just the current sheet
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = CurrentZoom 'Restore the original Zoom
End Sub
```