# Getting a series trend line equation to a shape text box

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to get the trend line equation from the first series in my chart to a shape text box placed elsewhere on the worksheet - however, I can only get the textbox to populate correctly when I'm stepping through the code line by line - during run-time it has no effect:

```
For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

    Set cht = chtObj.Chart

    For Each srs In chtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
        srs.Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = True 'Display the labels to get the value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyDataSheet").Shapes(slopetextboxes(k)).TextFrame.Characters.Text = srs.Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text
        srs.Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = False 'Turn it back off
        Exit For
    Next srs

    k = k + 1 ' for the slope textboxes

Next chtObj
```

Note that `slopetextboxes` is an array containing the names of ~6 shape text boxes.

As far as I know there's no way to get the trend line data label without stopping to display it. I've tried storing it in a string first, `DoEvents`, and turning `Application.ScreenUpdating` back on, all to no avail. I'm stumped here.

**EDIT:** It appears that by placing `DoEvents` after `.DisplayEquation = True` I'm able to have *some* of my shapes populate correctly, but not all. Still appears to be some kind of run-time issue.

**BOUNTY EDIT:** I've moved ahead to grab the slopes with a formula ran into the data itself, but I still don't understand **why I can't grab the chart's `.DataLabel.Text` during run-time**. I can grab it when stepping through, not during run-time. It appears to just take the PREVIOUS series slope and place it in the shape (or a cell, it doesn't even matter where the destination is). `DoEvents` placed in different spots yields different outcomes, so something must be going on.

Comment: You can get the trend line equations from the data directly with standard formula instead of the graph.

Comment: @ScottCraner Is there a built in formula to get it in y = mx + b format, or do I need a UDF?

Comment: You can easily concatenate: `="y = " & SLOPE(Ys,Xs) & "x + " & INTERSECT(Ys,Xs)`

Comment: @ScottCraner That could work... I'll probably use that if I can't figure out a way to take it from the chart data label directly - which I still don't understand why I can't.

Comment: Hmm - probably not helpful, but I was able to extract the equation to a range using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484453/trendline-equation-copy-paste-in-cell/)

Comment: @BigBen Very similar to my approach, but I'm still not able to grab the value from it during run-time.

Comment: These are shapes with text, not text boxes, correct? Also, maybe dumb question, but are you sure you're on the correct sheet (i.e. why use `ActiveSheet`)? I can successfully write the equation to shapes using an array of names and toggling `DisplayEquation`

Comment: @BigBen Understandable question - I am on the correct sheet. And I removed the `Array()` part from the `Shapes()` since I'm only doing one shape at a time - I know shapes can be finicky, might that affect why I'm not able to populate them at run-time?

Comment: @BigBen I certainly don't have to use `ActiveSheet` here, but I do for a bunch of miscellaneous reasons regarding `Worksheet_Change()` events, ActiveX controls and some zoom issues I've had in the past (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493633/code-that-changes-chart-position-requires-my-target-sheet-to-be-activated))

Comment: what is `Shapes(slopetextboxes(k))` ? I just tried `Sheet2.Shapes(1).TextFrame.Characters.Text = srs.Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text` and it worked. The shape is just a rectangle.

Comment: @cyboashu `slopetextboxes` is an array of shape names (like "shpLocation1", "shpLocation2", "shpLocation3"), etc.

Comment: @ScottCraner Trying to use your solution at this point, but `INTERCEPT` returns an insanely high number instead of a 0.0## decimal... any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: not without seeing your values.

Comment: @ScottCraner I can see that the issue is because I'm using dates like `1/1/2014, 4/1/2014, 7/1/2014` for my known x values instead of numbers like `1, 2, 3`. I'm assuming my dates are being interpreted in the 40,### format.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I would have another column that calculates the number of days from the minimum, `=A1-MIN($A$1:$A$10)` or something to that effect.

Comment: Reproduced in 2013. Clearly a bug. Only workaround I found was to add `srs.Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Select` before reading its `Text`.

Comment: I think I got it working with my answer. I just stored the equations into a collection and then iterated over a collection of textboxes and filled them with equations.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to have the data labels turned off? It seems that leaving the data labels in place makes it work fine.

Comment: @jcrizk I don't want to display the slope on the chart itself - I display it to the side in another table.

Comment: @BrakNicku By the way, the `Select` trick worked perfectly, even when changing the chart's source data - Still wondering *why* this needs to be done...

Comment: @dwirony You might consider leaving the equations visible but making the font color the same as the background and moving them to a blank area. That way you don't need to worry about the timing of the trend lines being turned on and off.

Comment: @DavidP I tried that, but two parts of my charts are slightly different shades of blue, and occasionally the equations populate on a crossover of the two.

Comment: @dwirony You can also change the font size to 1 so that they take up as little space as possible. Even if the equation is black on white it's barely visible at that font size, and it's less likely to span a transition between background colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written this off as a bug - The only workaround was discovered by BrakNicku which is to `Select` the `DataLabel` before reading its `Text` property:

`srs.Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Select`

Not a sufficient solution (since this can cause some issues during run-time), but the only thing that works.

Answer (score 4):

Updated with better understanding of the bug. This works for me in excel 2016 with multiple changes to the source data (and therefore the slope)

I tried myChart.refresh - didnt work. I tried deleting and then re-adding the entire trendline, also didnt work.

This works for everything but the first case. First case needs to be hit twice. Same as for .select

If you try and delete trendline even after assigning its text to textbox, this wont work

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()
Dim ws                                  As Worksheet
Dim txtbox                              As OLEObject
Dim chartObject                         As chartObject
Dim myChart                             As chart
Dim myChartSeriesCol                    As SeriesCollection
Dim myChartSeries                       As Series
Dim myChartTrendLines                   As Trendlines
Dim myTrendLine                         As Trendline

    Set ws = Sheets("MyDataSheet")
    Set txtbox = ws.OLEObjects("TextBox1")

    For Each chartObject In ws.ChartObjects
        Set myChart = chartObject.chart
        Set myChartSeriesCol = myChart.SeriesCollection
        Set myChartSeries = myChartSeriesCol(1)
        Set myChartTrendLines = myChartSeries.Trendlines

        With myChartTrendLines
            If .Count = 0 Then
                .Add
            End If
        End With

        Set myTrendLine = myChartTrendLines.Item(1)

        With myTrendLine
            .DisplayEquation = True
            txtbox.Object.Text = .DataLabel.Text
        End With
     Next chartObject
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll give it a shot soon.

Comment: Didn't get the chance to test today, I'll try tomorrow

Comment: Still haven't had the chance to test, I will tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: This code failed line on line `myTrendLine.DisplayEquation = True` with "Method 'DisplayEquation' of object 'Trendline' failed."

Comment: better understand your problem and now have a solution that works. i think your issue with myTrendLine was case specific? Like you have multiple trendlines or something lol. I am using excel 2016. I also tried a few other variations, may give a better idea of what problem is

Comment: This code is creating 1 additional trendline in each chart each time it runs. Fails with `Unknown error 1004` during 254th iteration (in 2013).

Comment: dont have time to test rn but threw in a trendline.delete

Comment: Tried with your new code, same results - nothing during run-time, works during step through. I'm going to be tossing this one up as a bug...

Answer (score 3):

Here's my code that seems to definitely work when just pressing F5:

Basically, I store the text in a collection, then iterate through all of the textboxes to add the text to the textboxes. If this wasn't precisely what you were asking for, then I hope this helps in any way.

```
Sub getEqus()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim srs As Variant
    Dim k As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim equs As New Collection
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim slopetextboxes As New Collection

    Set ws = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    'part of the problem seemed to be how you were defining your shape objects
    slopetextboxes.Add ws.Shapes.Range("TextBox 4")
    slopetextboxes.Add ws.Shapes.Range("TextBox 5")

    For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        Set cht = chtObj.Chart

        For Each srs In chtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
            srs.Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = True 'Display the labels to get the value

            equs.Add srs.Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text

            srs.Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = False 'Turn it back off
        Next srs

    Next chtObj


    For i = 1 To slopetextboxes.Count

        'test output i was trying
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 7).Value = equs(i)
        slopetextboxes(i).TextFrame.Characters.Text = equs(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Pictures of what the output looks like when i just press the button

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I won't have access to my work computer until Monday, I'll give it a test then.

Comment: Wow, this actually worked! I'm really impressed. Why does this only work with a collection? I'm going to do a few more tests before awarding bounty, stay tuned...

Comment: I have no clue why it worked with a collection; I had a hypothesis and tested it.

Comment: I am getting exactly the same results as OP's code (Excel 2013): first run - correct results, after changing source data and rerunning - wrong results (old equations).

Comment: @BrakNicku Okay so the problem still persists, no? This was the issue I was having - it would display the previous chart's slopes...

Comment: I tried testing it on my work pc and I think what is happening in my answer is that when I initially debug it somehow stores the text, but when I hit F5 at any time after debugging, it works. What the fuck dude lol

Comment: @jcrizk Sorry to unmark correct answer : / This problem still persists. It HAS to be a bug but I don't know how to pinpoint where and why.

Comment: @dwirony _Okay so the problem still persists, no?_  Yes, it does. And as I already said in my comment to the Q - it is a bug. Not sure if it is only 2013, I do not have any other for tests. But `srs.Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Select` workaround did work for me in all tests. Did it fail for you in some cases?

Comment: @BrakNicku The bug also occurs in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - I loop through multiple charts on `Sheet1`, toggling `DisplayEquation` and then writing the equation to a textbox/shape on the different worksheet. I used `TextFrame2.TextRange` but `TextFrame` worked as well, if you prefer that. I wrote to both a regular text box, as well as a shape, which was probably overkill as the syntax is the same for both.

This gets the trendline equation from the first `Series` - it sounded like you didn't want to loop through all the `Series` in the `SeriesCollection`.

```
Sub ExtractEquations()
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    Dim slopeTextBoxes() As Variant
    Dim slopeShapes() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    slopeTextBoxes = Array("TextBox 1", "TextBox 2", "TextBox 3")
    slopeShapes = Array("Rectangle 6", "Rectangle 7", "Rectangle 8")

    For Each chtObj In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects

        With chtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1)
            .DisplayEquation = True
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MyDataSheet").Shapes(slopeTextBoxes(i)).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = .DataLabel.Text
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MyDataSheet").Shapes(slopeShapes(i)).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = .DataLabel.Text
            .DisplayEquation = False
            i = i + 1
        End With
    Next chtObj
End Sub
```

Comment: Yet again, this code *works*, but only when I'm stepping through it in line by line in the editor - when I try to run the subroutine on its own, nothing happens. Very frustrating! I don't think Excel is grabbing the shapes at run-time!

Comment: So is it even entering the `For` loop - can you `Debug.Print chtObj.Name`? What else do you have going on in the sheet - you mentioned `Worksheet_Change` events?

Comment: It enters the loop and completes everything just fine - `Debug.Print chtObj` returns Charts 1 through 6 as expected (those are their names). This worksheet doesn't have any change events (other similar ones do). Again, it works fine stepping through the code, but running it without break points results in nothing.

Comment: What about `Debug.Print .DataLabel.Text` within the `With... End With`?

Comment: When I `Debug.Print .DataLabel.Text` on a different category set, running it through without break points returns the PREVIOUS chart's slope - the slope is inaccurate for the current series being displayed. Looking at the chart I can clearly see there is only one series as well (titled "All"). Yet when I step through line by line, it properly debug.prints the accurate slope and changes the shapes.

Comment: This has got to be a bug of some kind.

Comment: Oh my god I figured it out. `Application.EnableEvents = True` + `DoEvents` fixed it. I didn't even have enable events disabled...

Comment: Do you have events on the "MyDataSheet" sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue running the code below and my solution was to run `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` between setting the trendline and querying the DataLabel. Note that screen updating was already enabled.

```
    'Set trendline to the formal y = Ae^Bx
    NewTrendline.Type = xlExponential
    'Display the equation on the chart
    NewTrendline.DisplayEquation = True
    'Add the R^2 value to the chart
    NewTrendline.DisplayRSquared = True
    'Increse number of decimal places
    NewTrendline.DataLabel.NumberFormat = "#,##0.000000000000000"
    'Enable screen updating for the change in format to take effect otherwise FittedEquation = ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Get the text of the displated equation
    FittedEquation = NewTrendline.DataLabel.Text
```

Answer (score -2):

If it works when you step through, but not when it runs then it's an issue with timing and what Excel is doing in between steps.  When you step through, it has time to figure things out and update the screen.

> FYI, `Application.Screenupdating = False` doesn't work when stepping
>   through code. It gets set back to `True` wherever the code pauses.

When did you give it a chance to actually do the math and calculate the equation?  The answer is that, you didn't; hence why you get the previous formula.

If you add a simple `Application.Calculate` (in the right spot) I think you'll find that it works just fine.

In addition, why should Excel waste time and update text to an object that isn't visible?  The answer is, it shouldn't, and doesn't.

In the interest of minimizing the amount of times you want Excel to calculate, I'd suggest creating two loops.

1. The first one, to go through each chart and display the equations
2. Then force Excel to calculate the values
3. Followed by another loop to get the values and hide the equations again.

---

```
' Display the labels on all the Charts
For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    Set cht = chtObj.Chart
    For Each srs In chtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
        srs.Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = True 'Display the labels to get the value
        ' I take issue with the next line
        ' Why are you creating a loop, just for the first series?
        ' I hope this is just left over from a real If condition that wan't included for simplicity
        Exit For
    Next srs
Next chtObj

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Get the Equation and hide the equations on the chart
For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    Set cht = chtObj.Chart
    For Each srs In chtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyDataSheet").Shapes(slopetextboxes(k)).TextFrame.Characters.Text = srs.Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text
        srs.Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = False 'Turn it back off
        Exit For
    Next srs
    k = k + 1 ' for the slope textboxes
Next chtObj
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

### *Update:*

I added a sample file based on your description of the issue.  You can select 4 different options in an ActiveX ComboBox which copies values to the Y-Values of a chart.  It shows the trend-line equation below, based on the formula & through copying the value from the chart into a Textbox shape.

Maybe 2016 is different, but it works perfectly in 2013.  Try it out...

[Shape Text Box Example.xlsm](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k28FS0f7IfVZKAoeLRUyH5Hu7U5IU8N8)

Comment: No dice - I added your code and tried `Application.Calculate` - same result - nothing during run-time, works perfectly fine when stepping through. The `Exit For` was placed in my code for the interest of this post, I have to loop through series because sometimes I have more than 1 (so I grab multiple slopes from the chart).

Comment: Did you have `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`?  if so, reset it before you run `Application.Calculate`.

Comment: I turn it on for the entire snippet of code - still nothing. It can't grab the value during run-time.

Comment: @dwirony, I don't get it; I can reproduce your exact problem, and the solution above works.  What version of Excel are you using anyway?  and how is the routine being called (Button/Event)?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016. The routine is called by an Active `ComboBox_Change` event. The main issue, reproduced above by two other people, is that when you're changing the chart's source data from one source to another, updating the slope value either grabs 1. the previous source data's slope or 2. nothing at  all. Try dynamically changing a chart's source data and updating the slope values at run-time.

Comment: After someone's above recommendation, the only workaround is to `Select` the data label after displaying it before reading it.

Comment: I just tried your workbook that you attached - the issue persists here in 2016. Changing the source drop-down box changes the formula, but the text box value stays the same. Again, stepping through works, but run-time produces no change to the textbox value.

Comment: I guess it's a new issue with 2016 then.  I don't have access to Excel 2016 right now to do any more testing, sorry.