# Excel VBA Trendline Data Label Text is Empty

Tags: excel, vba, trendline

I made this code a year or so ago and it's been working fine. Recently, however, it broke. I am assuming there was a Windows update that changed the way Excel's macros worked with charts. The pertinent sections of my code perform the following:

1. Create an XY Scatter chart on a "prep" worksheet
2. Create a trendline for each data series on the XY Scatter
3. Parse each trendline text for slope and R^2, coping them as text onto another "summary" worksheet

What I've found is that Step 1 and 2 work fine, but when I try to parse the trendline text (expecting something like y = 0.0289x + 143), I get an empty string (see the commented out MsgBox, below). What's weirder is that when the Macro finishes (or fails) the chart updates and the text shows normally.

```
' Create the graph for the linear part of the data set
Worksheets(PrepSheetName).Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$B$19:$G$38")
' ActiveChart.Name = "Linear"
'MsgBox "Past linear creation"

' Add each data set to the chart individually
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
For i = 1 To 5

    ' Construct a string like ='Data'!$C$19:$C$38
    YValues = "='" & PrepSheetName & "'!$" & DSMeasCol(i) & "$"
    YValues = YValues & CStr(PrepDataStart) & ":$" & DSMeasCol(i) & "$"
    YValues = YValues & CStr(PrepDataEnd(i))

    ' Construct a string like ='Data'!$C$19:$C$38
    XValues = "='" & PrepSheetName & "'!$" & DSCmdCol(i) & "$"
    XValues = XValues & CStr(PrepDataStart) & ":$" & DSCmdCol(i) & "$"
    XValues = XValues & CStr(PrepDataEnd(i))

    ' Give the chart values
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = YValues
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = XValues

    ' Create a trendline for the chart
    Dim TL As Trendline
    Set TL = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Trendlines.Add(Type:=xlLinear, Forward:=0, _
        Backward:=0, DisplayEquation:=1, DisplayRSquared:=0, _
        Name:="LC" & CStr(i) & " Trend")
    TL.DisplayEquation = True
    TL.DisplayRSquared = False

    ' Exract the trendline formula
    Dim Eqn As String
    TL.Select
    'MsgBox "Trendline Text: " + TL.DataLabel.Text

    Eqn = Split(TL.DataLabel.Text, "=")(1)
    ' ... and place it on the coversheet ...
    CoverSheet.Cells(CSResults(i), CSFitSlope).Value = Split(Eqn, "x")(0)
    CoverSheet.Cells(CSResults(i), CSFitOffset).Value = Split(Eqn, "x")(1)

    'Find the RSquared of the Trendline
    TL.DisplayEquation = False
    TL.DisplayRSquared = True
    TL.Select
    Eqn = TL.DataLabel.Text
    Eqn = Split(TL.DataLabel.Text, "=")(1)

    ' ... and place it on the coversheet ...
    'CoverSheet.Cells(CSResults(i), CSFitCorr).Value = Eqn

Next i
```

If I try to run diagnostic code to parse the tredline datalabel text after running the macro the first time, it sees the text. When running the diagnostic code, though, I can't change the type of trendline data that is shown. I would expect, for example, that if I run:

```
 TL.DisplayEquation = True
 TL.DisplayRSquared = False
 MsgBox "Should show Equation."
 TL.DisplayEquation = False
 TL.DisplayRSquared = True
 MsgBox "Should show R^2."
```

... that I should see the trendline data label only show the equation when the first message box appears and the second message box should freeze the screen such that only the the R^2 is showing. When I run code like this, though, I find that my assumption is not true: The datalabel stays frozen until the macro completes, even with `ScreenUpdating = True` It seems like my charts aren't updating when the macro runs, but only updates at the end.

I've tried putting `DoEvents` and `Application.Recalculate` after creating the trendline, but it just causes my Excel to crash. Adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` or False doesn't seem to help, either...

Any ideas? I'm at a total loss...

Please let me know if I haven't provided enough information or anything is unclear.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably similar to [Getting a series trend line equation to a shape text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502097/getting-a-series-trend-line-equation-to-a-shape-text-box)

Comment: Perhaps related indeed. I have tried adding: `TL.DataLabel.Select` before `MsgBox "Text: " + TL.DataLabel.Text`, but I still get an empty string in the MsgBox.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be a bug.

Comment: Maybe you're more interested in solving your problem than obtaining a workaround, but depending on your version of Excel, you could feed your X and Y values to the `LINEST()` function -- from which you could then construct the equation.

Comment: `Option Explicit`, declare all your variables, avoid `.Select` and `.Activate`, qualify all your ranges. Given all that, I should be surprised you lasted a year without erroring out, but I am currently dealing with code that has been around for a few years that should have died when first started!

Comment: I'm seeing that I actually already have Option Explicit set, although I'm not 100% sure what it does. Also, I generally only use .Select and .Activate where necessary, but trying to solve this has left me adding lots of these calls where I wouldn't otherwise. Insofar as using LINEST, that may be a path forward. I don't really care about solving THIS problem or working around it; I just need my sheet up-and-running so that Production can work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using chillin's suggestion and used LinEst. It seems this is a bug in how Excel handles Chart DataLabels during Macro execution, as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502097/getting-a-series-trend-line-equation-to-a-shape-text-box). To summarize, my code is almost the same as above, but with the following change using LinEst instead of parsing the Trenline's DataLabel:

```
' Create a trendline for the chart
Dim TL As Trendline
Set TL = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Trendlines.Add(Type:=xlLinear, Forward:=0, _
Backward:=0, DisplayEquation:=1, DisplayRSquared:=0, _
Name:="LC" & CStr(i) & " Trend")      

' Generate the trendline constants and place them on the summary sheet
CoverSheet.Cells(CSResults(i), CSFitSlope).Value = "=INDEX(LINEST(" & YValues & "," & XValues & ",TRUE, TRUE), 1)"
CoverSheet.Cells(CSResults(i), CSFitOffset).Value = "=INDEX(LINEST(" & YValues & "," & XValues & ",TRUE, TRUE), 1,2)"
CoverSheet.Cells(CSResults(i), CSFitCorr).Value = "=INDEX(LINEST(" & YValues & "," & XValues & ",TRUE, TRUE), 3)"
```